# Problema ordenamiento con Arrays Java

Tags: java, array, bucle-for, condiciones, bucles

Tengo un array que se puede llenar con cualquier variable.

```
Así empieza el array
A[0]=13
A[1]=8
A[2]=48
A[3]=3
A[4]=0
```

y deseo obtener un array el cual mantenga la posición  del anterior pero los datos los deseo de 0, 1, 2, 3, etc. con respecto del mayor o menor dependiendo de caso.

```
Así debe de terminar 
B[0]=3
B[1]=2
B[2]=4
B[3]=1
B[4]=0
```

tengo entendido que se hace con ciclos for y if pero no logro mantener las posiciones

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar el siguiente metodo:

```
public static void burbuja(int[] A) {
    int i, j, aux;
    for (i = 0; i < A.length - 1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < A.length - i - 1; j++) {
            if (A[j + 1] < A[j]) {
                aux = A[j + 1];
                A[j + 1] = A[j];
                A[j] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
}
```